# recursion condition in different position make different output

Tags: java, recursion, conditional-statements

The question is:

Write a boolean method, that get positive integer n>0.
and return, if this n can be write as a power of 3's.
each power, can appear at the sum maximum one time.

For example: if n = 37 f() return true, because: 3^0+3^2+3^3 = 37
if n = 38 f() return false.

I was able to solve the problem, but only when i wrote the condition (num==0) before
the condition (num < 0 || 3^I > num).

can anyone explain me why?

the 2 versions of the code:

```
public static boolean sumPower3(int num)
    { return sumPower3(num,0); }
    // version 1(output: false):
    private static boolean sumPower3(int n,int i)
    {
        int p3i = (int)Math.pow(3,i);
        if(p3i>n || n<0){return false;}
        if(n==0){return true;}
        return sumPower3(n-p3i,i+1) || sumPower3(n,i+1);
    }
    // version 2 (output true):
    private static boolean sumPower3(int n,int i)
    {
        int p3i = (int)Math.pow(3,i);
        if(n==0){return true;}
        if(p3i>n || n<0){return false;}
        
        return sumPower3(n-p3i,i+1) || sumPower3(n,i+1);
    }
```

Comment: 3^i is always greater than 0, if num==0 then 3^i>n is true, you enter the if condition and return false.

Answer (score 2):

For version 1, consider what happens in the last layer of recurision.

At this point, `n` is already equal to 0. The answer to this should be `true`, and that is what should be returned.

However, `(int)Math.pow(3,i);` is definitely larger than or equal to 1. This means that when `n == 0`, `p3i>n` will evaluate to `true` and your function returns `false`, giving an incorrect answer.

You should write the `n == 0` condition first as `p3i>n || n<0` should only return false when `n != 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative "math" solution:

```java
public static boolean sumPower3(int num) {
    if (num == 1 || num == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (num % 3 == 2) {
        return false;
    }
    return sumPower3(num / 3);
}
```

Comment: You don't even need recursion. Just a for loop will do (which is more time and memory efficient)